# How to inject mocks into a Camel route builder with Quarkus?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel, quarkus

There's a Camel route builder registered in Quarkus and using some injected beans:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterForReflection
public class RouteForStoutBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Inject
    TrafficLight trafficLight;

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("direct:route-for-a-stout")
            .choice()
                .when(trafficLight.isGreen())
                    .bean(bar)
            .end();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to cover that route with a test:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class RouteForStoutTest {

    @Inject
    ProducerTemplate producer;

    @InjectMock
    TrafficLight trafficLight;

    @InjectMock
    Bar bar;

    @Test
    void testWithGreenLight() {
        Mockito.doReturn((Predicate) exchange -> true).when(trafficLight).isGreen();
        Mockito.doAnswer(invOnMock -> invOnMock.getArgument(0)).when(bar).order(ArgumentMatchers.any());

        producer.sendBody("direct:route-for-a-stout", "stout");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the route is built before the beans used on that are mocked. So the real predicate returned by the real TrafficLight bean is used instead of one returned by the mock.

Is there a way to inject mocks into a route builder before the route is built?

Comment: I don't know quarkus enough to have an idea about the root cause but did you have a look at this repo: https://github.com/aldettinger/camel-quarkus-inject-mock ? Maybe you'll find in it some configuration element that's missing in your project.